# How to create a distributable RESTful API in python for a database?

Tags: python, database, rest, api

I apologize in advance if the below-given information looks insufficient.

The programming language to be used throughout is python.

I am trying to understand the procedure to create an API for a database that can be accessed by anybody around the world. Like an API "https://testing.org/api/someendpoint" where there is a proper hostname and want to create a API like that, not like "http://localhost:5000/users" this as explained in the link "https://www.roytuts.com/python-rest-api-crud-example-using-flask-and-mysql/".(please consider that i have no exp in  making a API)

I also don't know if i need to host my database(current location - local computer) somewhere else to create a global API.

So how do i go from making a local api link to a global api link.

The database is a normal database with a single table which contains information like name, id, sales info, time, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also don't know if i need to host my database(current location -
>   local computer) somewhere else to create a global API.

You might want to host in the cloud e.g. [Google Appengine](https://appengine.google.com) or Google Compute Engine. You can do it with Google Appengine.

Implementation, which you mention that you already did, can be done in many ways. If you choose Google Appengine you can just base your code on the examples in that manual. Any implementation details may depend on your specific environment but you might want to consider my current way. I just read the data from a database and then output it as JSON.

Example:

```
    cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('GetSomeDataYouWant') # Calling a stored procedure
    thelist = []
    for result in cursor.fetchall():
        my_dict = {
            "name": result[1],
            "sales": result[2],
            "info": result[3]
        }
        thelist.append(my_dict)
    cursor.close()
    mariadb_connection.close()
    return get_success_response(thelist)
```

Helper function:

```
def get_success_response(response):
  return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' # Required for CORS support to work
    },
    'body': json.dumps(response)
  }
```

Comment: I hope you dont mind me asking another question sir....After creating an API locally what are the next steps? Like what do i do to bring the api into the production side..?

Comment: @HarshitKhandelwal It's called "deployment". You package your application locally and then you issue a command and copy it to the production side. This procedure is called deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools that can make this job a lot easier:

https://www.djangoproject.com/ which comes complete with a web interface, admin, and much else besides. The most useful thing is it has an ORM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) - a way of treating database objects and python objects similarly.

You may also find https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ a useful addition - it makes REST APIs for Django. If your interface requirements are clean and well defined you should be able to get going in no time. You don't need it to make Django have a REST interface - but it takes a lot of the repetitive work away.

Comment: Sorry but this didnt help me as it does not help me create an API for a global atmosphere. It explains about creation of a API in the local device. Please consider while answering that i have no experience in creating a API....This is a new avenue for me

Comment: From my understanding of what you want a global accessible API is just a local API but on a port exposed to the internet. Develop locally and then deploy externally. Or do you mean something else by a global API?